# Post Security Trimming for People Search Results

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search, security-trimming

In the context of our SharePoint platform we implemented a security trimming of the search results because some external users should not be able to see internal items under certain conditions. We implemented the post security trimming using the interface ﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿ISecurityTrimmerPost and we registered our security trimmer with the crawl rule http://*. The trimming is working perfectly.

Recently we decided to deploy the people search, we created a new content source for our MySiteHost and crawled the profile store. For the same reason we would like to trim the people search results for some external users. We tried to implement a new security trimmer using the same interface ﻿ISecurityTrimmerPost. Because the url of the mysite are matching the same rule http://* we just registered the new security trimmer.

Unfortunately, the new security trimmer is never called by SharePoint. It seems like the people are not items like sites or pages and that the security trimming can't be applied on such kind of items. We tried to remove all securiy trimmers and to register only the one for the people but once again the trimmer class is never called for people but it is for sites, pages, ...

Can someone help me to find what i'm doing wrong or can someone confirm me that the post security trimming not working for people items?

Thank a lot for your help

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

People are crawled on either sps3:// or sps3s:// I would start by changing your Protocol. If you can you could also look at ContentClass since people are their own content class.  `(ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople)`

Comment: Hi Matthew,  thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately i have to use the sps3 protocol otherwhise the user profile aren't crawled. If i set an http or a sts3 protocol on the mysitehost the crawler find only the site.

Comment: No, I mean the protocol on YOUR trimmer. If you can. I have NEVER needed to do this since filtering the accounts on import is an easier approach.